# How to use variables from application.yaml in SpringBoot kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I need to use variables declared in my applications.yaml file, as an example all it is:

```
num_error:
    value: "error"
    result: 1
```

And I have a class trying to call it like the following:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "num_error")
@Component
class NumError {
    companion object {
        lateinit var value: String
        lateinit var result: Number
     }
 }
```

However, when I try and call this class using `NumError.value` I get an the following error

```
lateinit property value has not been initialized
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property value has not been initialized
```

What have I done wrong, why is this error happening?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have `companion object`, and since Spring boot 2.2 you can have ConstructorBinding to make it work.

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "num_error")
data class NumError(
    val value: String, val result: Number
)
```

Make sure you include following dependency

```
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
}
```

**EDIT**

For older versions, define the variables directly in the class instead of `companion object`.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "num_error")
class NumError {

  var value: String = "some default value",
  var result: Number? = null
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this i get two erros, 'Unresolved reference: ConstructorBinding' and 'Data class must have at least one primary constructor parameter'

Comment: what is your spring-boot version?

Comment: im using 2.1.3.RELEASE, im unable to update it though.

Comment: doesnt seem to be working now using 'ConversionErrorProperties().value' to get the value but it always uses that default value same with getting result. :(

Comment: you should not be initializing the class, instead autowire the bean `@Autowired ConversionErrorProperties props;`

Comment: is it possible to use @ Autowired w/o using @ Component on the class?

Comment: yes, it is possible. Define the bean using `@Bean` in your configuration class